# Transforming/collapsing bivariate distribution to a univariate distribution

Tags: posterior, joint-distribution, odds-ratio

I have a joint probability density function f(x,y) numerically in R. X is the probability males get a disease; Y the probability females get the disease. I want to extract from this bivariate data the univariate density for the odds ratio. That is I have a some function T(X,Y) and need the density function of T. In this case T=X(1-Y)/[Y(1-X)]. Many thanks.

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf) of some help to start. Hopefully it gives you enough background to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks yes that helped. I realize I first need to tranform from X,Y to T,W using the Jacobian where T=X(1-Y)/[Y(1-X)] and W=Y then marginalize out W.

Comment: If you have trouble you might turn your comment into a more specific version of your question - I suspect it's one that would be likely to get an answer.